# Ubuntu: Allow only one certain command with certain arguments to run for a restricted user

Tags: bash, ubuntu

In my Ubuntu 18.04 system I have a restricted user which should be able to run only one certain command with only specific arguments, nothing else.

The restricted user is using `/bin/rbash`, so he wouldn't be able to use `ls, nano, mkdir`, etc. unless I provide a symlink to its bin folder.
But in my case I want him to allow to use a command with only specific arguments, no matter what else arguments the command provides.

Let's say for example the command its called "`simplecommand`" and its arguments which can be passed are `create, edit, delete`

A normal user can then run these commands for example:

```
simplecommand
simplecommand create "userA" "abc" 
simplecommand create "userB" "abc" --information="important to know"
simplecommand edit "userC" 123
simplecommand delete "userZ"
simplecommand delete "userZ" 542 --comment="No needed because..."
```

So he would be able to use `simplecommand` with `create`, `edit` and `delete` (no matter what else can be provided by the arguments itself).

However, a restricted user should only be able to use `create` like this

```
simplecommand create "userA"
simplecommand create "userB"
simplecommand create "userC" "abc" --information="important to know"
```

Not even "`simplecommand`" itself should the restricted user be allowed to run, only when the user writes "`simplecommand create`" (no matter what follows after the argument `create`)

Is this even possible? I can't find a solution on that.

Comment: Looks like `sudo` can get you close: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279125/allow-user-to-run-a-command-with-arguments-which-contains-spaces

Comment: Wrap the command in a bash script and provide the user only with this script that calls `simplecommand` and allows only what you want to be allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is possible in three steps.

1. Limit user PATH variable to `/some/specific/bin` in place of
   /bin;/usr/bin etc. See here: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/65822
2. Wrap your simplecommand in a utility/script which will accept only
   specific arguments and will pass it to simplecommand (like what @MichalH suggested). (The utility
   can be written in any language be it bash, python, C ...)
3. Place your utility to `/some/specific/bin` from the first step

Comment: So far so good, seems to be a good solution, but when I try this, I am receiving this error: `/home/myuser/bin/my_utility.sh: line 11: simplecommand: command not found`
`simplecommand` is in my case located at `/usr/bin/`. The problem here I see is, that when I would add `/usr/bin/simplecommand` to the PATH, the restricted user would be able to use any other arguments beside the create argument in the terminal. Do you have any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Oh, you should call the command using the full path! Call `/usr/bin/simplecommand` in place of just `simplecommand`. No PATH should be altered for this.

Comment: Was it really that easy? Anyway, it did work! Thank you very much! But aside from this solution: Is it possible to restrict the command `simplecommand` somehow, so that the user can run it on a terminal without using a script?

Comment: Restricting command arguments requires some logic so you have to describe it in some form anyway I think. For example in Python it can be as easy as providing command line samples to `docopt` package...